# Cant register FireBase user from Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I am unable to register an user from my app written in Flutter. I am also unable to get some form for error message. I can debug and see my createUser function is called and the arguments looks good. Nothing happens after I call "FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword". No exception and nothing is printed in the FireBase emulator console. What am I missing here? Here is what I got:

```
Emulator:
Running on 127.0.0.1:9099
```

main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,);

  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);
  } catch (e) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print(e);
  }

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: "Foo",
      home: buildContent(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Registration function:

```
void createUser() async {
    print("createUser()");
    try {
      final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: nameController.text,
        password: passwordController.text,
      );
      //final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: nameController.text, password: passwordController.text);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Edit:
I keep getting this message when i call "createUserWithEmailAndPassword"

W/System  (26859): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.

Answer (score 0):

In your `createUser()` Function i think you're sending empty values to firebase

request parameters like this and try it again

```
void createUser(String name, String Password) async {
    print("createUser()");
    try {
      final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: name,
        password: password,
      );
print("User Created Success);
      //final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: nameController.text, password: passwordController.text);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have made the changes you suggested and added a print in order to see the email and password passed to the function. Both email and password are defined and looks good.

Is there a log for the FireBase emulator I could look at in order to understand what is happening? I feal like I am walking in the dark here.

Answer (score 0):

So after some trail and error I ended up adding:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

To the manifest file:
...\my_project\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

I am not sure I like the "fix" as I think the requests are sent unencrypted. A google search gives me this description:

```
Android 6.0 introduced the useCleartextTraffic attribute under application element in android manifest. The default value in Android P is “false”. Setting this to true indicates that the app intends to use clear network traffic
```